Averages of random variables
Let us assume that $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d-s with finite expectations. Form the random variable $$Y := \limsup_n {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$ From the Strong Law of Large Numbers, it is clear that $Y$ has finite expectations, too. I wonder whether there is an alternative, more elementary proof of this statement. (Unfortunately, the reverse Fatou lemma is useless.)
